# How to get child node value which has namespace on it?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am completly new to XSLT and my goal is to retrieve value from a node which has namespace on it. My XML looks as below.

```
<WBIFNMsg>
    <AppData>
        <AppName>INFM</AppName>
        <MsgType>Notification</MsgType>
        <MsgStatus>Success</MsgStatus>
    </AppData>
    <AppMsg>
        <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:setr.010.001.03">
            <SbcptOrdrV03>
                <MsgId>
                    <Id>29331095XXXXML</Id>
                    <CreDtTm>2019-06-07T10:30:43.681+02:00</CreDtTm>
                </MsgId>
            </SbcptOrdrV03>
        </Document>
    </AppMsg>
</WBIFNMsg>
```

I am trying to get the value of Id tag which is under document/SbcptOrdrV03/MsgId/ via the xslt. As the document tag has the namespace I have included it in my xslt but still I couldn't retrieve the value.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:b="urn:swift:xsd:setr.010.001.03" exclude-result-prefixes="b">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <data>
            <messageDataApps>
                <field>
                    <fieldName>SENDER.STP</fieldName>
                    <value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="b:WBIFNMsg/b:AppMsg/b:Document/b:SbcptOrdrV03/b:MsgId/b:id"/>                                    
                    </value>
                </field>
            </messageDataApps>                                                                                                          
        </data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Appreciate if anyone could help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `Document` and its descendants are in a namespace and require using a prefix when addressing them. Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="b:WBIFNMsg/b:AppMsg/b:Document/b:SbcptOrdrV03/b:MsgId/b:id"/>
```

try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="WBIFNMsg/AppMsg/b:Document/b:SbcptOrdrV03/b:MsgId/b:Id"/>
```

---

Note also that XML is case-sensitive: `b:id` is not the same thing as `b:Id`.